# Print/query class instances in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I am just getting started with Isabelle.  I have a file like this:

```
theory Z
  imports Main Int 
begin

value "(2::int) + (2::int)"

lemma "(n::int) + (m::int) = m + n"
apply(auto) done

print_locale comm_ring_1
print_interps comm_ring_1

end
```

Most of this works as I expected: Isabelle tells me that 2+2=4, and it knows how to prove that n+m=m+n, and it prints the axioms for a commutative unital ring.

However, I expected that the line "print_interps comm_ring_1" would cause Isabelle to tell me that it knows that the integers are an instance of the class comm_ring_1 (given that this fact is certainly proved in the file Int.thy in the standard library, which we have imported).  But Isabelle does not in fact tell me that.

Is there some other way to ask Isabelle to list all the instances of comm_ring_1 that it knows about?  Or to query specifically whether int is an instance of comm_ring_1?  I have looked in the reference manual for such a command, but cannot find one.

Answer (score 0):

Every type class in Isabelle defines a locale of the same name, but they are not the same. The commands `print_locale` and `print_interps` consider only the locale aspect of a type class. Type class registration with `instance` or `instantiation` does not register the type as an interpretation of that locale. Therefore `print_interps` does not list the types that have been proven instances of type classes. This is done by the command `print_classes`.